# PyPDF2 creating blank pdfs in adobe but not chrome?

Tags: python, pdf, adobe, pypdf, pymupdf

So i have made code that will:

- combine all pdfs in "_Input" file
- save it so there are two sheets per page
- resize and rotate the pages so its A4 landscape
- rename the file

all of this works

however!

The pdf when opened in google chrome shows me what is it supposed to look like, however when i open it with adobe acrobat, it doesnt work. How can i modify it so it can be viewed in adobe acrobat.

It has be able to be used in acrobat as I need to send it to someone who only has acrobat, please help.

I tried using PyMuPDF, but the same thing happens.

I have also tried using ChatGPT to help, but it seems to use a sighlty outdated PyPDF2 and keeps asking me do make changes that end up looping

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter, PageObject,Transformation
import PyPDF2
import fitz


def combine_pdfs(input_folder, output_file):
    pdf_writer = PdfWriter()
    pdf_writer2 = PdfWriter()

    # Iterate through all PDF files in the input folder
    for filename in os.listdir(input_folder):
        if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
            filepath = os.path.join(input_folder, filename)

            # Add each page from the current PDF to the combined PDF
            with open(filepath, 'rb') as pdf_file:
                pdf_reader = PdfReader(pdf_file)
                for page_num in range(len(pdf_reader.pages)):
                    pdf_writer.add_page(pdf_reader.pages[page_num])

    # Save the combined PDF
    if len(pdf_writer.pages)%2!=0:
        blankpage = pdf_writer2.add_blank_page(width=595.2, height=842)
        pdf_writer.add_page(blankpage)
    with open(output_file, 'wb') as output_pdf:
        pdf_writer.write(output_pdf)


def Two_per_page(input_pdf_path, output_pdf_path):

    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(input_pdf_path)  #read the document
    totalPages = len(pdfReader.pages)       #get total num of pages

    pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()
    input1 = PdfReader(open(input_pdf_path, "rb"), strict=False)
    output = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()

    for page in range(0, totalPages,2):

        page1 = input1.pages[page]
        page2 = input1.pages[int(page)+1]

        tempPage = pdf_writer.add_blank_page(width=1191, height=842)

        tempPage.merge_page(page2,False)
        op2 = Transformation().translate(tx=595, ty=0)
        tempPage.add_transformation(op2)

        op1 = Transformation().translate(tx=0,ty=0)
        page1.add_transformation(op1) ;tempPage.merge_page(page1)


        output.add_page(tempPage)

    output.write(open(output_pdf_path, "wb"))

def rotateAndScale(input_pdf_path, output_pdf_path):
    # A3 and A4 dimensions in points
    a3_width = 1191  # Width of A3 in points
    a3_height = 842  # Height of A3 in points

    a4_width = 595  # Width of A4 in points
    a4_height = 842  # Height of A4 in points

    # Calculate the scaling factors
    scale_width = a4_width / a3_height  # Swap width and height for landscape to portrait
    scale_height = a4_height / a3_width

    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(input_pdf_path)  #read the document
    totalPages = len(pdfReader.pages)       #get total num of pages

    pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()
    input1 = PdfReader(open(input_pdf_path, "rb"), strict=False)
    output = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()

    for page in range(0, totalPages):

        page1 = input1.pages[page]

        tempPage = pdf_writer.add_blank_page(width=a4_width, height=a4_height)

        tempPage.merge_page(page1,False)
        op3 = Transformation().rotate(90).scale(scale_width,scale_height).translate(tx=a4_width)
        tempPage.add_transformation(op3)

        output.add_page(tempPage)

    output.write(open(output_pdf_path, "wb"))

def deleteAndRename(rnFilePath,rnFile,file1,file2):
    delFile1 = file1
    delFile2 = file2

    old_pdf_file_path = os.path.join(rnFilePath, rnFile)

    user_input = input("Enter batch: ")

    new_pdf_file_path = os.path.join(rnFilePath, str(user_input) + ".pdf")

    try:
        os.rename(old_pdf_file_path, new_pdf_file_path)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f'The PDF file {old_pdf_file_path} does not exist.')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'An error occurred: {e}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    progLoc = os.getcwd()

    # input location
    input_folder = os.path.join(progLoc, "_Input")

    # output location
    output_file = os.path.join(progLoc, "_Output", "combined_pdf.pdf")

    print("Combine: - Start")
    combine_pdfs(input_folder, os.path.join(progLoc, "combined_middle_pdf.pdf"))
    print("Combine: - End")

    print("Two-per-page:    - Start")
    Two_per_page(os.path.join(progLoc,"combined_middle_pdf.pdf"),os.path.join(progLoc,"combined_middle2_pdf.pdf"))
    print("Two-per-page:    - End")

    print("rotateAndScale:     - Start")
    rotateAndScale(os.path.join(progLoc,"combined_middle2_pdf.pdf"),output_file)
    print("rotateAndScale:     - End")

    print("deleteAndRename:     - Start")
    deleteAndRename(os.path.join(progLoc, "_Output"),"combined_pdf.pdf",os.path.join(progLoc,"combined_middle2_pdf.pdf"),os.path.join(progLoc,"combined_middle_pdf.pdf"))
    print("deleteAndRename:     - End")
```